# BizTalk is sending request to WCF service and WCF service request with NULL fields in object

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-wcf

I am consuming the service in BizTalk and created a schema using that. With that schema, I did some mappings and XML output of map, I am sending to WCF service. From the map, I am getting values correctly in XML to be sent to WCF service. But in WCF service request object, I am getting some fields NULL.

Please help me if someone has solution on this problem. I am stuck because of this issue.